# Computing the Laurent series of $\frac{1-z^4}{z^4}$ at $z_0=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

> I want to find the Laurent series for $$\frac{1-z^4}{z^4}$$ at $z_0=0$

I would write
$$
\frac{1-z^4}{z^4}
= \frac{1}{z^4} \frac{1}{\frac{1}{1-z^4}}
= \frac{1}{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} z^{4k}}= a_1z^4 + a_2 z^8 +\ldots
\implies a_i=1
$$

Is that right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that is not right. Just note that$$\frac{1-z^4}{z^4}=z^{-4}-1.$$That's all: the Laurent series that you're after is $z^{-4}-1$.

Comment: oh.....:( Thank you. But where is the mistake in my calculation?

Comment: Yes. It is by no mean true that$$\frac{1}{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} z^{4k}}= a_1z^4 + a_2 z^8 +\cdots$$

Comment: I still don't get the mistake?

Comment: My mathematical conversions were right?

Comment: I don't know what a mathematical conversion is, but I know that if a pwer series begins with $z^4$, then its inverse begins with $z^{-4}$, not with $z^4$.

Comment: Ok I understand. But how can I get from here $\frac{1}{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} z^{4k}}= a_1z^4 + a_2 z^8$ to your result?

Comment: I have no idea and I don't know where you got the idea that $\frac1{\sum_{k=1}^\infty z^{4k}}=a_1z^4+a_2a^8$, whatever that means.

Comment: Ok then it's simply wrong. Thank you very much for your help:)

Comment: If my answer was useful perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: I already did it. Thank you again:)